# python - find the occurrence of the word in a file

Tags: python, file, count, cpu-word

I am trying to find the count of words that occured in a file. I have a text file (`TEST.txt`) the content of the file is as follows:

```
ashwin programmer india
amith programmer india
```

The result I expect is:

```
{ 'ashwin':1, 'programmer ':2,'india':2, 'amith ':1}
```

The code I am using is:

```
for line in open(TEST.txt,'r'):
    word = Counter(line.split())
    print word
```

The result I get is:

```
Counter({'ashwin': 1, 'programmer': 1,'india':1})
Counter({'amith': 1, 'programmer': 1,'india':1})
```

Can any one please help me? Thanks in advance      .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `update` method of Counter.  Example:

```
from collections import Counter

data = '''\
ashwin programmer india
amith programmer india'''

c = Counter()
for line in data.splitlines():
    c.update(line.split())
print(c)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'india': 2, 'programmer': 2, 'amith': 1, 'ashwin': 1})
```

Comment: +1 Just what I was going to post - this makes nice use of the specialised `Counter.update` method and doesn't require reading the entire file to memory...

Answer (score 8):

```
from collections import Counter;
cnt = Counter ();

for line in open ('TEST.txt', 'r'):
  for word in line.split ():
    cnt [word] += 1

print cnt
```

Answer (score 5):

You're iterating over every line and calling Counter each time. You want Counter to run over the entire file. Try:

```
from collections import Counter

with open("TEST.txt", "r") as f:
    # Used file context read and save into contents
    contents = f.read().split()
print Counter(contents)
```

Comment: @jadkik94 If he's processing every line within that block either way, why would it make a difference?

Comment: @Anorov What happens if you have a 50gb file that you want to count? (Tha just so happens to only have 3 unique words)....

Comment: @JonClements I was about to say this too, even if here it's unlikely to be the case. But a best practice is a best practice...

Comment: Yep, you guys are right actually. I was forgetting about the default generator behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict 

def read_file(fname):

    words_dict = defaultdict(int)
    fp = open(fname, 'r')
    lines = fp.readlines()
    words = []

    for line in lines:
        words += line.split(' ')

    for word in words:
        words_dict[word] += 1

    return words_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE_NAME = 'file.txt'

wordCounter = {}

with open(FILE_NAME,'r') as fh:
  for line in fh:
    # Replacing punctuation characters. Making the string to lower.
    # The split will spit the line into a list.
    word_list = line.replace(',','').replace('\'','').replace('.','').lower().split()
    for word in word_list:
      # Adding  the word into the wordCounter dictionary.
      if word not in wordCounter:
        wordCounter[word] = 1
      else:
        # if the word is already in the dictionary update its count.
        wordCounter[word] = wordCounter[word] + 1

print('{:15}{:3}'.format('Word','Count'))
print('-' * 18)

# printing the words and its occurrence.
for  (word,occurance)  in wordCounter.items(): 
  print('{:15}{:3}'.format(word,occurance))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('input.txt', 'r')
data=f.read().lower()
list1=data.split()

d={}
for i in set(list1):
    d[i]=0

for i in list1:
    for j in d.keys():
       if i==j:
          d[i]=d[i]+1
print(d)
```

Comment: f = open('input.txt', 'r') # opening the file
data=f.read().lower() 
list1=data.split() ##list created with all words

d={} # empty dictionary
for i in set(list1):
    d[i]=0 #adding all elements of the list to a dictionary and assigning its value as zero.

for i in list1:
    for j in d.keys():
       if i==j:
          d[i]=d[i]+1 #checking and counting the values.
print(d)

#sample file contents (input.txt) --- "Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern return pattern"
#program output: {'non-overlapping': 1, 'of': 1, 'matches': 1, 'return': 2, 'pattern': 2, 'all': 1}