# Find the count of the words in the text file using python

Tags: python, file, count, cpu-word

I had text file named as `content_data` with the following content

```
A house is house that must be beautiful house and never regrets the regrets for the baloon in 
the baloons. Find the words that must be the repeated words in the file of house and ballons
```

1. Now i need to read the file using python and need find the count of each and every word
2. We need to implement the result in the form of a dictionary like below format

   `{'house':4,'baloon':3,'in':4........},`

   i mean in the format of `{word:count}`

Can anyone please let me know how to do this

Comment: Please, see similar questions on SO first. E.g. this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083119/python-find-the-occurrence-of-the-word-in-a-file

Comment: Are you allowed/supposed to use any imports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation

counter = Counter()
with open('/tmp/content_data') as f:
  for line in f:
    counter.update(word.strip(punctuation) for word in line.split())

result = dict(counter)

# note: because we have
#   isinstance(counter, dict)
# you may as well leave the result as a Counter object

print result
```

Comment: The call to `dict(...)` is redundant, I know OP might look at the result and say "How can i get this back to a normal dictionary", but it's probably better to just tell OP counter is in fact a dictionary.

Comment: Yeah, I'll add a comment to that effect.