# I want to create a program that can analyze downloaded text file in python

Tags: python, text

The analysis included following:

1. How many words in the text data?
2. How many times the keyword appear in the text data?

   ```
   import os
   f= open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'test1.txt'), 'r')
   dataString =f.read()
   ```

This code is just opening the downloaded text file.
I have no idea what to do next. I'm totally stuck.
Please help me. It's just okay to give me some advice or hint..

Comment: This is a question which does not embrace the spirit of SO... We're not here to explain to you *how* stuff is done. This is a problem easily solvable by reading Python [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html).

Comment: My guess is that this question will be closed soon as there are plenty of q/a on SO that already address strategies for dealing with the problem.  I would encourage you to not get frustrated by it being closed/  What I have learned is that before I really want to ask a question I start trying to come up with an explicit question.  As I type the question the SO engine populates possible related questions just below the question header.  Look at those carefully. you will often find your answer.  I did that just now to confirm and I found great answers to your question.

Comment: thank you for answering my stupid question. I actually don't know much about programming and english. I'm a student in somewhere in asia. It's hard for me to do some programming assignment. Because there are few contents about python programming that are written in my language. I've visited python docs web page, but I can't understand the documents and don't know how to use. I am only grasping at straws here anyway..

Comment: It is not stupid it is just naive.  The Python docs are good once you have invested some time into the language the Docs were written by geniuses.  I found as I started learning to start thinking about these problems one very small step at a time.  1. How do I read a file into python.  2. How do I identify words. 3. How do I count words?  If you get really focused on one thing at a time you will find this site to be an awesome resource.  When you can't find an answer then you ask a question but keep it focused.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python - find the occurrence of the word in a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083119/python-find-the-occurrence-of-the-word-in-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the number of unique word you will need to do something like this to count everything without cases like "hello, " interfering with the calculation.

```
print len(set(re.findall('\w+', dataString.lower()))) # Number of unique words
print len(re.findall('\w+', dataString.lower())) # Total number of words
```

To display the number of counts of a specific word you can use [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk).

```
words = re.findall('\w+', dataString.lower())
print len([word for word in words if word == 'hello'])
```

Or you can use [count](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_count.htm).

```
print words.count('hello')
```

Answer (score 1):

In `dataString`, you'll want to go through each word and count it. So you'll need a way to identify individual words in a string. You can either use the [`string.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method or some [regex](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to split the words up a little more cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

I wont solve your issue, but I will explain how you would do each thing because Stackoverflow was not created to do your work for you, but I am going to point you to what you have to do:

How many words:

`dataString.split()` will return a list where each item is a word in the file, so let us do

How many times a word repeats:

if you want to check how many times a specific word occurs, you now know how to get every word in a list, just iterate through that list and you can either use your own counter and add 1 to it every time a word is `in dataString.split()` or you could use [the collections Counter class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Answer (score -1):

To get the word count, use

```
f = open('test.txt, 'r')
text = f.read()
f.close()
words = text.split(None)
ec = len(words)
```

To get how many times a word occurs in a file, add

```
swc = 0
for word in words:
    if word == 'word2count':
        swc +=1`.
```

Comment: Not so great advice. `wc = len(words)` and `swc = words.count('targetword')` are greatly preferred over brute force iteration. Learn the standard lib and API for the core data types.

Comment: The line `for word in words do:` is invalid: `do` is not a Python statement.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: Thank you for the advice. I forgot about that command.

Comment: @BioGeek: Thank you for pointing out that error. I do that a lot. I got it from VB
NET.

Comment: What happens if the word is followed by a special character? e.g. `hello,`