# uppercase and count words in a file french characters

Tags: python, count, words

Maybe someone can help me because I can't find any answers. I'm french and it's kind of complicated to count all the words of a file without missing anything (é, à, è...).

That's why I wanted **to convert all the words of my file to uppercase**, and then **started to count the words**. I'm quite new with the functionalities of Python and I don't really know how to use it from a file.

I've started to do that :

```
import re 
from collections import Counter 
f = open("vie.txt") 
words = re.findall("[a-zA-Z_]+", f.read()) 
count = len(words) 
print ("Number of total words: %s" % count) 
f.close()
```

And I was thinking about something like that :

```
  hist= dict()
f = open("vie.txt")

def process_line(ligne, hist):
    ligne = ligne.replace('-', ' ')

    for mot in ligne.split():
        mot = mot.strip(string.punctuation + string.whitespace)
        mot = mot.upper()
        hist[mot] = hist.get(mot, 0) + 1

hist = process_file("vie.txt")

def total_mots(hist):
    return sum(hist.values())

print('Number of total words:', total_mots(hist))
```

But it's too long, and I want something shorter without using a dictionary.

Comment: num unique words: `len(set(open("README.md").read().upper().split()))`.   num words: `len(set(open("README.md").read().split()))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - find the occurrence of the word in a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083119/python-find-the-occurrence-of-the-word-in-a-file)

Comment: The above dupe should be easily editable to get upper case - use `line.upper.split()` rather than `line.split()` to get upper case words

Answer (score 0):

Converting all words to uppercase will not help you with accents:

```
>>> "é".upper()
'É'
```

However, you can use [Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/), just `pip install unidecode`, then

```
>>> import unidecode
>>> unidecode.unidecode("ééé èèè").count(unidecode.unidecode("êêê"))
2
```