# How to count word frequency in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I uploaded an excel text file. I want to count the number of times each word occurs, for instance:

Output:

```
was 2
report 1
county 5
increase 2
```

Code:

```
 news = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\farid-PC\\Desktop\\Tester.xlsx')
 pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 1000)
 print(news)
 #implement word counter?
```

Current Output:

```
   Text
0  Trump will drop a bomb on North Korea
1  Building a wall on the U.S.-Mexico border will take literally years
2  Wisconsin is on pace to double the number of layoffs this year.
3  Says John McCain has done nothing to help the vets.
4  Suzanne Bonamici supports a plan that will cut choice for Medicare
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us a few rows of your dataset (you can cut and paste `news.head().to_dict()` or something like that). Also, the code you provided doesn't attempt to solve the problem, it just shows how you loaded the data. Have you attempted anything so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - find the occurrence of the word in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083119/python-find-the-occurrence-of-the-word-in-a-file)

Comment: Show us how data looks like by posting output of `df.head(5)`. You can use `collections.Counter` as well to count the frequency.

Comment: I tried to use news.read() but gives an error that dataframe doesn't have attribute read.

Answer (score 6):

With pandas, using `split`, `stack` and `value_counts`:

```
series = df.Text.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()
```

---

A python-based alternative using `chain.from_iterable` (to flatten) and `Counter` (to count):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

counter = Counter(chain.from_iterable(map(str.split, df.Text.tolist())))
```

Re-create a Series of counts using:

```
series = pd.Series(counter).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Which is identical to the pandas solution above and should be much faster since there is no stacking involved (`stack` is a slow operation).

Comment: Thank you for the help.