# one liner syntax python

Tags: python, syntax-error

I want to count the number of each word in a file, and I'm trying to write it
as one line code, but I get an invalid syntax error and I don't understand why, 
or how to change it.

my code:

```
def print_words(filename):
  my_file = open(filename, 'r')
  word_dict = {}
  for line in my_file:
    line.lower()
    words_in_line = line.split(" ")
    word_dict[word] += 1 if word_dict.get(word) else word_dict[word] = 0 
      for word in words_in_line
```

error message:

```
word_dict[word] += 1 if word_dict.get(word) else word_dict[word] = 0 for word in words_in_line
                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i also tried to write it a little different (code will follows) but still got the same error. but when i deleted the "= 0" the syntax was ok (when i deleted it from the original one liner the syntax was still invaid).

```
my_file = open(filename, 'r')
word_dict = {}
for line in my_file:
  line.lower()
  words_in_line = line.split(" ")
  for word in words_in_line:
    word_dict[word] += 1 if word_dict.get(word) else word_dict[word] = 0
```

Comment: You're making us guess what, and where, the error is.  Edit the question to include the full error message.

Comment: An assignment can not be part of an expression.

Comment: Also, you're using `word` as an index before having defined `word`.

Comment: This might be a good time to use `Counter` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083119/python-find-the-occurrence-of-the-word-in-a-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a regular expression to get the words and the Counter class (from collections) to count them:

```
from collections import Counter
import re
with open("testfile.txt") as file: words = Counter(re.findall("\w+",file.read()))
```

If the file is huge, you may need to process it line by line:

```
with open("testfile.txt") as file: words = Counter( w for line in file for w in re.findall("\w+",line.upper()))
```

Comment: 1. what if i have a really big file of tens of GB, is there a more efficient way than reading the whole file at once? is this the most efficient way? 2. how can i count it in case insensitive?

Answer (score 0):

`def print_words(filename):
  my_file = (open(filename, 'r').readlines())
  word_dict = {}
  for line in my_file:
    line.lower()
    words_in_line = line.replace("\n","").split(" ")
    for word in words_in_line:
        if word in word_dict:
            word_dict[word] =word_dict[word]+ 1
        else:
            word_dict[word] = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Use a default dict instead of a regular dict.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def print_words(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as my_file:
        word_dict = defaultdict(int)
        for line in my_file:
            for word in line.lower().split(" "):
                word_dict[word] += 1

    ...
```

Or go a step further and use a `Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

def print_words(filename):
    flatten = chain.from_iterable
    with open(filename, 'r') as my_file:
        word_dict = Counter(flatten(line.lower().split(" ") for line in my_file))

    ...
```